# Errors in my ruby script

Tags: ruby

I am getting an error I don't understand.  It runs how I intended but throws an error at the end.  I am still new to ruby but I know it has something to do with my for loops.

This is my code

```
nums = Array.new(24){Array.new(80){'X'}}
system('cls')
for i in 0..24
    for j in 0..79
            print nums[i][j]
    end
 end
```

And this is the error messages

```
K:/Ruby 2/RubyInvaders.rb:5:in block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from K:/Ruby 2/RubyInvaders.rb:4:in each'
from K:/Ruby 2/RubyInvaders.rb:4:in block in <main>'
from K:/Ruby 2/RubyInvaders.rb:3:in each'
from K:/Ruby 2/RubyInvaders.rb:3:in <main>'
```

Its ok to offer better ways to do this but I would also like to understand why I am getting this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an array with 24 elements and then a loop with 25 iterations.  When you try to print the 25th iteration of that loop, the array position doesn't exist.  If you change `for i in 0..24` to `for i in 0..23`, the error should be addressed:

```
nums = Array.new(24){Array.new(80){'X'}}
system('cls')
for i in 0..23
  for j in 0..79
    print nums[i][j]
  end
end
```

To amplify on Jon's comment, ruby ranges created with the `...` operator are exclusive and won't use the highest specified value (as opposed to the `..` operator, which is inclusive).

And--while your approach to looping is valid--it's not idiomatic for ruby.  Something like this would be more common:

```
nums = Array.new(24){Array.new(80){'X'}}
system('cls')
(0..23).each do |i|
  (0..79).each do |j|
    print nums[i][j]
  end
end
```

Comment: I see now.  I have been staring straight at the problem but kept looking at the for loops and never checked my original declaration.

Comment: You could also use `0...24` and `0...80`, which is a little easier to comprehend.

Comment: "creating" => "are creating", "of with" => "of", "and then create" => "creating"

Answer (score 3):

When `i` is `24`, `nums[i]` is `nil`, and you are calling `[]` on it.